# compare Image and Sound

Tags: android

```
Guys please tell me it is possible to compare image with sound
```

I am doing image application , in this application at a time one sound

will be produced ,

, at the same time four images will loading ,

If the image and sound are same then go to next images and continue the same.

For that I need to compare the images with sounds .

Because when the sound arise the correct image need to click ,

if the other images are clicked do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a map?  Put the correct correlation between the image and sound in a map and check to see if it matches.

Comment: Thank you for the immediate response till i did not try map But I hope this is the good idea . Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Volume level for the Sound when it's played and set the proper image. otherwise image data and sound data comparison is not possible AFAIK